# Pairing Problems 8bitdo SFC30 with Recalbox

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I can't pair my 8Bitdo SFC30 (SNES-Controller).

Recalbox keeps showing the message "No bluetooth controllers found".

I tried the following:

- Installing the newest RecalboxOS 4.0.0 Beta4 on the Raspberry Pi (3)
- Installing the newest firmware on the SFC30 (2.6.8 Beta)
- Starting the controller by pressing Start+R (as recommended by the manufacturer and in forums about the topic)
- Clear all pairing informations on the controller AND on Recalbox AND
  rebooting
- Connecting the controller through USB AND trying to pair it with
  bluetooth

Does anyone have a solution to this? Has anybody experienced the same problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[8bitdo on recalbox wiki page](https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/8bitdo-on-recalbox-(EN)) says both <kbd>START</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for SNES30 and just <kbd>START</kbd> for **SFC30**.
Strange as they are the same stuff.
So go try both.

But, anyway, if you don’t have one of the [compatible Bluetooth dongles](https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Compatibility-(EN)#bluetooth-dongle), it cannot work before they release recalbox version **4.1** which only will bring **internal Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth support**.

Comment: Thanks @jesus2099. I didn't know about the lack of internal Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth Support. No wonder it didn't work. I'll try again with both ways AND a compatible Bluetooth dongle. I'll post the results here and Close the post afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

krustowsky,

I had the same issue with my 8BITDOO SFC30 gamepad.
In my case there was a default bluetooth password "0000" for the gamepad wich caused the issue when trying to pair via the frontend.

From the frontend screen you have to go open a terminal window and pair, connect and trust your gamepad there - I used bluetoothctl for this task

It is all properly described there:

https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Connect-bluetooth-controller-manually-(EN)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! It would be idea if you could include all relevant information from the link in your answer, in case the link breaks in the future. Since you are new here I would recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how things work around here.